# Batch file to copy GoogleDrive to External

Tags: batch-file

I've written a batch file to copy my GoogleDrive to my external (E:).
However, only the first two directories are copied.  What am I doing wrong?

```
@echo off
set T=%time:~0,5%
set dir=%date:/=-% %T::=-%
echo The target folder is "%dir%".
xcopy /s /c /y "C:\Users\22097244\Google Drive\*.*" "E:\Backups\GoogleDrive\%dir%\"
```

Any assitance shall be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps if you were to show us the name of the third directory, we may not need to bring in the clairvoyants.

Comment: Wow, my first post ever is being answered with sarcasm. What a welcome site this is. Magoo, the names of the directories copied are irrelevant though. Let's say I have directories Apples, Pears, Bananas, Pineapples, etc. in my drive, only Apples and Pears are copied to the external.